# Django: 404 error in urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I have two `urls.py` files.

In `project/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

In `project/blog/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^(?P<slug>[a-z-]+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^(?P<slug>[a-z-]+)/comment/$', 'comment'),
)
```

Then I tried to browse these URLs:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/ (404)

http://127.0.0.1:8888/hello-world/ (404)

http://127.0.0.1:8888/admin/ (It worked)
```

Django version: `1.4 pre-alpha SVN-16985`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with specific details about A) what you expected to happen, B) how the results did not meet your expectations, and C) your request for us?

Comment: When you see 404 page check if links you want to use are in 404 list. If there are not you have something configured wrong. Try to use @user589983 answer. And if it will not help then paste here 404 error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the http://127.0.0.1:8888/  error, change your regular expression to:

```
(r'^$', include('blog.urls')),
```

Regarding the http://127.0.0.1:8888/hello-world/ error: There could be many things causing this.  First, check that you have a blog title that actually returns the slug 'hello-world'.